# Could not run application on IOS, issue about pod in Flutter

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

Whenever I clean up the `project/ios` folder and then try `pod install` It throws an error:

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: ({repo-path}/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework)
```

There are some kinda solution ways listed in StackOverflow and in other forums. 
**A few of them:**

- removing `project/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` and after that, trying `pod install`.

**But it throws another error:**

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing GoogleUtilities 7.2.0 (was 7.2.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 10 dependencies from the Podfile and 28 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most useful solutions are listed down below:

- Removing `ios/Podfile.lock` then running:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

If it didn't work, so, if you get a new issue like this:

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: ({repo-path}/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework)
```

You should try to fix it by following steps:

- remove the `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework`
- `cd ios`
- `pod install`

---

**The way that worked in my situation:**

I just recreated the project from the beginning, and then I replace `.git/` `lib/`, `pubspec` ... (essential directories and files for making project run)