# How can i fix Flutter IOS run problem with VScode?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I'm using cloud firestore in my flutter application and I want to run app on IOS.
When i run my app on iOS device its give me that error:

```
/ios/Runner/generatedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found
    @import cloud_firestore;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

this is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.0.0'


end
```

and when i add pods i also do flutter clean and pod install and after flutter run. And i faced this problem

Comment: Please provide the version of packages you added (firebase packages)

Comment: My pubspec packages: cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2 | firebase_core: ^1.3.0 | firebase_auth: ^1.4.0

Comment: Okay, open your projects ios folder, then open podfile and share the platform version, (It should be commented like `# platform :ios, '9.0'`).

Comment: I was mentioned above

Comment: Oh sorry I had not seen

Comment: Please take look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66288817/14247462

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1-flutter clean
2-rm -rf Pods
3-rm Podfile.lock
4-sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
5-Pod clean
6-pod init
7-flutter pub get
8-flutter run
```

Perfect 
**make sure the package is up to date**

Answer (score 0):

Just change version of cloud_firestore: in pubspec.yaml like below

```
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
```

Then run:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Comment: My packages already. cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2 | firebase_core: ^1.3.0 | firebase_auth: ^1.4.0

Comment: Did you try adding GoogleServiceInfo.plist from xcode?

Open ios module in Xcode > Right Click on Runner folder > Add files to "Runner" and select your GoogleServiceInfo.plist

Comment: Yes i was try this correctly. I was get new warning: The IOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0 , but the range of supported deployment target version is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')

Comment: Try changing deployment target to 9.0